# How to show a single notification icon in the status bar for multiple notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm currently showing notification with this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSound(sound)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.h) 
    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true)
    .setContentText(message)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(message))
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`setGroup()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setGroup(java.lang.String)) key to show notifications in group.

```
final static String GROUP_KEY_EMAILS = "group_key_emails";

// Build the notification, setting the group appropriately
Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender1)
         .setContentText(subject1)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
         .build();

// Issue the notification
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId1, notif);
```

Set [`setGroupSummary()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setGroupSummary(boolean)) to set summary for a group of notifications